# React, insert a wrapper for the last two elements in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, react-hooks, mapping

I have a list of 5 elements

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function NumberList(props) {
  const numbers = props.numbers;
  const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    <li key={number.toString()}>
      {number}
    </li>
  );
  return (
    <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  );
}
```

How can i add a div container wrapping the two last elements of the list?

The result has to change from

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

to

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <div>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </div>    
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, i have commented your answer why i can not accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **You would need to use `index` and have a condition for that:**

**Something like this:**

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function NumberList(props) {
  const numbers = props.numbers;
  const firstList = numbers
    .slice(0, numbers.length - 2)
    .map(number => <li key={number.toString()}>{number}</li>);
  const lastList = numbers
    .slice(-2)
    .map(number => <li key={number.toString()}>{number}</li>);
  return (
    <ul>
      {firstList}
      <div>{lastList}</div>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

**Or a bit more cleaner in this live snippet:**

```js
function App() {
  function NumberList(props) {
    const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    const firstList = numbers
      .slice(0, numbers.length - 2)
      .map(number => <li key={number.toString()}>{number}</li>);
    const lastList = numbers
      .slice(-2)
      .map(number => <li key={number.toString()}>{number}</li>);
    return (
      <ul>
        {firstList}
        <div>{lastList}</div>
      </ul>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {NumberList()}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, my question was about to add a div wrapping the last two items, your answer is that the last two items have a div wrapping their selves